# Woocommerce- How to display product addons data on order details

Tags: woocommerce, add-on

I installed Woocommerce 2.1.7 and Woocommerce Product Addons 1.1 with wordpress 3.9.
You know the extension, Woocommerce Product Addons 1.1 costs $49 and I wanted custom input(text) value to be shown into the order details from dashboard. But it shows only the item title! 
I'm new to woocommerce and extensions and begging your help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved my issue....It was my product add-ons plugin needed to be updated!!

Comment: That's weird. I am facing the same issue, and it's already up-to-date with WooCommerce to its latest update.